# Highlight Current Link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using [this technique](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/25/asp-net-mvc-highlight-current-link.aspx) for highlighting current links (e.g. how the "Questions" link is highlighted on this very page you're looking at). I changed the code a little bit and came up with this extension method:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(
        this HtmlHelper helper,
        string content, string action, string controller)
    {
        var routeData = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
        var currentController = routeData["controller"];
        var currentAction = routeData["action"];

        var builder = new TagBuilder("li")
        {
            InnerHtml = content
        };
        if (String.Equals(action, currentAction as string,
                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            &&
           String.Equals(controller, currentController as string,
                   StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            builder.AddCssClass("active");
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
    }
```

It works fine, But that’s some ugly code. I use the extension method this way:

```
@Html.MenuLink("<a href=" + @Url.Action("MainPage", "Ticket") + "><i class='fa  fa-fw fa-home'></i>Ticket Page</a>", "MainPage", "Ticket")
```

As you can see, part of that isn't strongly typed.

Do you have any ideas to improve the extension method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that I see that I would change is the if statement

> ```
>     if (String.Equals(action, currentAction as string,
>               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
>         &&
>        String.Equals(controller, currentController as string,
>                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
>     {
>         builder.AddCssClass("active");
>         return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
>     }
> ```

I personally don't like having a conditional that spans over multiple lines,  so the first thing that I would do is to take the boolean conditions and make them into boolean variables and then use them inside the conditional.  I think it would be easier to read.

```
bool isCurrentAction = String.Equals(action, currentAction as string,
          StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
bool isCurrentController = String.Equals(controller, currentController as string,
           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (isCurrentAction && isCurrentController)
{
    builder.AddCssClass("active");
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
}
```

And since you are returning `builder` immediately after the if statement, there isn't really a reason to return inside the if statement, it is rather redundant.  Just delete that from the if block

```
bool isCurrentAction = String.Equals(action, currentAction as string,
          StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
bool isCurrentController = String.Equals(controller, currentController as string,
           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (isCurrentAction && isCurrentController)
{
    builder.AddCssClass("active");
}
```